# Drawing/plotting a circle with some radius around a point (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use scatter to plot some points. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1,2, 1.5], [2, 1, 1.5])
plt.show()
```

Now I also want a circle with radius 0.5 around point [1.5, 1.5] in the plot. How do I do that? I know that there are edgecolors, so that I could just set them to 'none' and then to some color. But those circles then have no radius of 0.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a circle around point, you can use plt.Circle as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([1,2, 1.5], [2, 1, 1.5])
cir = plt.Circle((1.5, 1.5), 0.07, color='r',fill=False)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')
ax.add_patch(cir)
plt.show()
```

I hope this solved your problem. And please let me know further.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know whether there are function like set_color for plt.Circle? I would like to change its color after it was created.

Comment: You can set the color by changing the `color='color name'`. In the above code, I set red color of the circle. Therefore, I put color='r' and also you can fill this circle using fill=True. Please let me know your further query.